# Is there a short-form for addresses with seven characters length?

Tags: transactions, wallet, public-key

So, I am confused about address/key length. I am aware that the length is 16-36 characters, but it seems that many people online when giving their public key use a short-form of 7 characters (being only a part of the full address) to receive coins. Also when I was first looking into Bitcoin I read something in a tutorial that mentioned this 7 character short form but I can no longer find said tutorial (was a page similar to bitcoin.com and coindesk). Does this even exist?

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the "firstbits" initiative?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are mentionning is [firstbits](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Firstbits). But this practice is now obsolete as it encourages address reuse, which reduces privacy.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to send funds to anyone using a partial address. The address is is an identifier of 26-35 alphanumeric characters starting with the number 1 or 3.